# Create an option menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a Soduko game in HTML and javascript. I want to make a user select the numbers
(0 - 9) instead of entering them.

Here is an example for one input (cell 0:0):

`<td><input id="c00" type="text" size="1" onclick="validate()"/></td>`

I would like the javascript code to display an option of 0-9 when that cell is clicked.

My idea is that.

```
if oncliked()
then display menu
document.getElementById("c00").value = selected value.
```

Comment: Why dont you just use the `select` tag instead of `input`?

Comment: Thought of that, but it does not look professional at all. That would even bore a kid.

Comment: Look at using knockout, if you gave the whole problem I can mock you up a knockout version which makes it very easy!

Comment: Looks like you know everything you need. What's your question?

Comment: How do I actually implement that in JavaScript.I know the pseudo-code, but need the JavaScript to do that.How to make a selection option entirely in JavaScript when the input text is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes instead of ids for your click event, like:

```
<td><input class="number-select" type="text" id="c00" size="1"/></td>
```

Then you can bind to all of them in jQuery:

```
$("input.number-select").click(function(){
    $("#tile-chooser").show();    
    ...
}
```

Inside this callback you can use

```
$(this).val()
```

to get or set the value of textbox.

Also on `click` you should show your numbers selector. You can do this by creating a div with `data-input-id` attribute where you will store `id` of textbox to fill.

Then in this `div` you can create 10 `divs` with digits on them and special class like `digit-tile` and attach callback to them:

```
$("div.digit-tile").click(function() {
    var inputId = $(this).parent().data("input-id");
    $("#" + inputId).val($(this).data("value"));
    $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

Your tiles can look like this

```
<div id="tile-chooser" style="display:none">
    <div class="digit-tile" data-value="1">1</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Add some CSS to this to look good and it should work.

Last thing you need to add is positioning of the div with tiles so it will be close to textbox but this out of scope of this question I think.

Comment: The thing is I am new in web based. Apologies, forgot to mention, We should only use pure javascript. Apologies again for including the Jquery tag. But thanks for the input.I will try to convert that to JavaScript.

Comment: Not using jQuery will produce more code but the idea will be the same. If you're new to JS, HTML and CSS then you anyway need to research topics like CSS absolute positioning, hiding/showing elements with styles, etc. If you get a full working solution here it still will be no good at all if you are not able to modify it to meet your exact requirements.

Comment: Thank you guys, will give it a try and see where it leads me.Thanks again guys.